# Plotly - python - How to loop through colors

Tags: python, colors, plotly-python

I have a simple plot. How do I loop through colors in a list of rgb colors?

```
import plotly.express as px

X1 = [1,2,3]
Y1 = [2,4,8]
Z1 = [3,6,8]

colors = ['rgb(255,0,0)','rgb(255,165,0)','rgb(0,0,255)']


cat = ['A','B','C']


    
figtest = px.scatter_3d(x = X1, y = Y1, z = Z1, color = cat)
figtest.update_traces(marker_color = [x for x in colors])
figtest.show()
```

What I got:
[image]

Comment: Can you mention the module name?

Comment: what is X1? I don't see it defined in the code.

Comment: @codester_09 plotly.express is used for plotting.

Comment: I've corrected the code, forgot to paste X1, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a dictionary of categories and then pass it through the color_discrete_map parameter like so - it'll then look up the color based on the cat value:

```
import plotly.express as px

X1 = [1, 2, 3]
Y1 = [2, 4, 8]
Z1 = [3, 6, 8]
cat = ['A', 'B', 'C']

color_map = {'A': 'rgb(255,0,0)', 'B': 'rgb(255,165,0)', 'C': 'rgb(0,0,255)'}

figtest = px.scatter_3d(x=X1, y=Y1, z=Z1, color=cat, color_discrete_map=color_map)
figtest.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use a list of specific rgb like this colors = ['rgb(255,0,0)','rgb(255,165,0)','rgb(0,0,255)']. I need to set a specific rgb to each point

Comment: Ah - ok - updated my answer based on that.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about discrete_map.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have to loop, just pass the list

```
X1 = [1,2,3,4]
Y1 = [2,4,8,9]
Z1 = [3,6,8,10]

colors = ['rgb(255,0,0)','rgb(255,165,0)','rgb(0,0,255)','rgb(0,1,133)']


cat = ['A','B','C','D']

figtest = px.scatter_3d(x = X1, y = Y1, z = Z1, color = cat, color_discrete_sequence = colors )

figtest.show()
```

[image: works]